# Spliting an equation based on blanks in C

Tags: c

I am coding a program which can calculate an equation which will be inputted by the user

```
Example) 1 + 999
```

Firstly, I though of using strtok in order to remove blanks and saving them into array. Since data format will be 'char' thus I was planning to use `atoi()` for int conversion.

Followings are my code

```
fgets(input, 100, stdin);

char equation[100] = {};
char *temp = strtok(input, " ");

while(temp != NULL)
{
    equation[order] = *temp;
    printf("Index: %d | %s\n", order++, temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Index: %d | Element: %c\n", i, equation[i]);
}
```

Problem is that I can't store them into array properly. Followings are the output result. (I just put printf for checking purposes only)

```
Index: 0 | 1
Index: 1 | +
Index: 2 | 999

Index: 0 | Element: 1
Index: 1 | Element: +
Index: 2 | Element: 9
```

Sorry for asking such questions, but I feel like I am missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You declare `equation` as a `char` array. When you assign to the array:

```
equation[order] = *temp;
```

You dereference `temp` which gives you a single character (the *first* character) of the string pointed to by `temp`.  So on your first printing, you're printing the strings pointed to by `temp`, but the second is printing the first char, which is all you've stored in `equation`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From what I understand, I shouldn't use pointer to assgin value from temp to equation. Is it correct?

Comment: `equation` may need to be an array of char arrays to store each token, and then you'd copy each token into that array using the appropriate string handling functions from string.h.